# search for tags in unanswered questions category

Tags: feature-request, search

How can I search for example "VB.NET" tag in unanswered questions ? When I write down a tag name in searchbox (on top of page) and press enter it shows all new questions by that tag. But when I click the "Unanswered" button it clears the searchbox and retrieves all Unanswered questions. So my aim is to search for example "VB.NET" tag in Unanswered questions. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want all VB.NET questions that have no answers, rather than Stack Overflow's definition of "unanswered", this search query will do that:

```
[vb.net] answers:0
```

If you're looking for a question with one or more answers but none accepted or with a positive score, then:

```
[vb.net] isanswered:no
```

Check out the [advanced search operators in the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). There are a ton of options.

Comment: Are there other properties we can search with this syntax? e.g. "unanswered questions with 0 **accepted** answers"

Comment: @Arc676 - I have edited my answer.