# Find questions in a tag I haven't answered? New search userqa?

Tags: support, feature-request, search

Similar but not the same as [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278199/search-for-tags-in-unanswered-questions-category) I want to find not just unanswered questions in a tag, but ones that I have specifically not answered myself yet.

This would be helpful as the subject matter expert for a tag where I have already answered many of the questions. I don't just want unanswered questions as I may want to add an answer to a question where no answer has been accepted yet. But I don't want to keep opening questions I have answered that haven't been accepted.

I have tried `is:question [tag] -user:1234` but this returned questions I had answered.

If no solution exists then I would request a feature to add a search param `userqa:1234` to find if the user is in related answers for a question or related questions for answers which could then be negated.
`is:question [tag] -userqa:1234`

Thanks to @BenVoigt's suggestion I was able to create a [search in SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/741754/questions-in-selected-tag-that-i-havent-answered-yet) which does what I want, **however** I really wish it was an option with **live data**.

Comment: How can you have an answer on *unanswered* questions? The "unanswered" state does not mean "has answers, but not one that's accepted". Unanswered, means "*no answers*", which can't be the case if you've answered the question.

Comment: @Makyen: I don't think the request is for unanswered questions, but all questions OP hasn't posted an answer to, regardless of if there are answers from other users or not.

Comment: This needs a join, since the tags are on the question, but your ownership applies to the answer.  The search box can't do this, but a SEDE query can.

Comment: That's probably correct. However, my comment was intended as a prompt for the OP to [edit] the question to clarify: " I don't just want unanswered questions as I may have already added an answer not accepted yet", among other statements which make it unclear if they're asking what we *think* they are asking.

Comment: @Makyen is that better now?

Comment: @Anthropic, Yes, that is more clear.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks I'd never heard of SEDE, I'll take a look.

Comment: SEDE almost works, I wrote a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/741754/questions-in-selected-tag-that-i-havent-answered-yet), however it would be nice if it was a tag that could run on live data as week old data doesn't quite help when I want to immediately show a list without ones I answered on the same day.  
  
But it does help a little so thank you very much for bringing it to my attention @ben-voigt