# Search for unanswered questions doesn't work with multiple tags

Tags: bug, tags, unanswered-questions

For example, searching for `[c++] [qt]` works correctly for all filters/sorting ([Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20qt), [Frequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20qt?sort=frequent&pageSize=30), [Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20qt?sort=votes&pageSize=30), [Active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20qt?sort=active&pageSize=30)), but when selecting [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%2b%2b%20qt), it seems to be showing the union of `[c++]` and `[qt]` (as if `[c++] or [qt]`), instead of the intersection.

It works correctly for single tags, or if applying the filter directly in the query (as explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278201/1485885)): [`[c++] [qt] isanswered:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%5Bqt%5D+isanswered%3Ano).

Am I doing something wrong? Did I miss something in the UI or documentation? Is it a bug?

Comment: I never noticed that as I rarely rely on the default behavior and prefer being explicit, so I tend to use `[c++] and [qt]` for your exemple to really get questions with both tags.

Comment: @Tensibai thanks; interesting fact, if I search for [`[c++] and [qt]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+and+%5Bqt%5D) the _Unanswered_ option is gone.

Comment: Indeed, the unanswered tab behave strangely

Comment: Yes, it should be better called something like "Without accepted answer"... although obviously having answers is not the same as to be _answered_ (correctly)

Comment: It's working correctly for me with the [new question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/369403). You could consider enabling this if you want to use the feature.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth thanks, I've opted in but I have to wait until it gets enabled for me, I'll test it as soon as I have it working

Comment: Oh, wait a moment, it behaves finicky with the new question lists as well. [c++][qt] and click unanswered -> [c++] or [qt]. Click unanswered, then enter [c++][qt] -> works correctly. I'll report this on MSE for the question lists. Anyway, you can get the intended results if it gets enabled for you.

Comment: @DidierL although it doesn't solve the problem, since the button itself keeps working incorrectly and I already knew about the advanced query instead, I understand it is a perfect duplicate of my question, thanks